# Test automation for Android applications

Tags: android, software-testing

I have worked on my first complex application. I would like to test it, using some professional services, like TestObject or TestDroid, but I am looking for some free alternatives of it. I have found only paid services in this topic.

Comment: You can [search StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+android+testing) for a lot of starting points.